# Is the closure of a linear variety a linear variety?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I know and have been able to prove that, if $L$ is a linear variety of a normed space $X$, i.e. a vector subspace $L$ of $X$ regarded as a vector space, then its closure $\bar{L}$ with respect to the topology induced by the norm is a linear variety too.

I wonder whether that is true for any topological vector space $X$ and its linear varieties, but cannot find any information about it. If that were true, can anybody write or link a proof?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify life a little by dealing with the subspace  $S = L - \{l\}$ (for any $l \in L$) instead.

So the question becomes if $S$ is a subspace, is $\bar{S}$ a subspace?

The key facts are continuity of scalar multiplication and addition.

Suppose $x \in \bar{S}$ and $\lambda \neq 0$. Suppose $U$ is open with $\lambda x \in U$. Then ${1 \over \lambda } U$ is an open set containing $x$ and so there is some $s \in {1 \over \lambda } U \cap S$ from which it follows that $\lambda s \in U$. Since $U$ was arbitrary, we have $\lambda s \in \bar{S}$.

Now suppose $x,y \in \bar{S}$ and $U$ be open with $x+y \in U$. By continuity of addition, we have open $U_x,U_y$ such that $U_x+U_y \subset U$. Hence we have $s_x \in U_x\cap S, s_y \in U_y\cap S$, and so $s_x+s_y \in U$. Since $U$ was arbitrary, we have $x+y \in \bar{S}$.

Comment: Forgive me if I don't understand one thing: is $S=L-\{l\}$ in sense of $L\setminus\{l\}$? If that's so, I don't see that it's a vector subspace, because I'm not sure $-l\in S$ would have its opposite $-(-l)$ in $S$... Moreover I don't see where you have used the fact that $S=L-\{l\}$ rather than $S=L$ considering $S$ any vector subspace in your proof, which I find wonderfully clear! Thank you so much again!

Comment: Generally, if $A,b$ are subsets of a vector space, $A-B = \{a-b| a\in A, b \in B \}$. You need to verify that $L$ is affine **iff** for any $l \in L$, $L - \{l\}$ is a subspace. It is slightly easier to show that $S$ is a subspace rather than $L$ is affine.

Comment: I didn't understand because I only intended $L$ as a vector subspace, not an affine one in general: now everything is clear to me. Go raibh maithe $\infty$ agat!!!

Comment: Tá failte romhat! The term linear variety generally means an affine set.